# Как правильно взаимодействовать между окнами в javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Есть основное окно, в нём поле и кнопка. По нажатию на кнопку открывается модальное окно с текстовым полем и кнопкой. Мы вводим текст в текстовое поле, жмём на кнопку и значение поля основного окна должно измениться. 
Как правильно это сделать?Не хочется делать кучу static полей, может есть какой-то более правильный способ?
(оба окна - разные классы)

Answer (score 3):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Optional;

public class TestSO extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Button btn = new Button("Text");
        btn.setOnAction(e -> {
            Dialog<String> dialog = new TextInputDialog("Enter new text here");
            dialog.setTitle("Change button text");
            Optional<String> optional = dialog.showAndWait();
            optional.ifPresent(btn::setText);
        });
        pane.setCenter(btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

В приведенном примере, при нажатии на кнопку, возникает модальное окно с текстовым полем и кнопкой. При введении текста в поле и последующим нажатием на кнопку поменяется текст на кнопке.

**P.S.** нужна 8 java

Comment: Спасибо, не совсем то, что мне было нужно, но узнал немного нового:)
Я сделал через шаблон Observer.
Из модального окна должно было поменяться поле основного и одна переменная ещё одного класса, так что Observer, на мой взгляд, идеально подошел:)

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Den
 */
public class JavaFXApplication78 extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    WindClass wc = new WindClass();
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button("Открыть модальное окно");
        Label lbl = new Label("Неизмененная метка");
        btn.setOnAction(act ->{
            wc.showWindow(lbl, primaryStage);
        });
        VBox root = new VBox(lbl,btn);

        Scene scn = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scn);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Основное окно");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

и второй класс

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

/**
 *
 * @author Den
 */
public class WindClass {
    public void showWindow(Label lbl,Window mod){
        Stage stg = new Stage();

        Button btn = new Button("Изменить метку");
        btn.setOnAction(act ->{
            lbl.setText("Метка изменена");
            stg.close();
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane(btn);

        Scene scn = new Scene(root, 150, 100);
        stg.setScene(scn);
        stg.setTitle("Новое модальное окно");
        stg.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        stg.initOwner(mod);
        stg.showAndWait();
    }
}
```